# Webdatarocks file size limitation question

Tags: webdatarocks

I know that the input data size limit for webdatarocks is 1mb. But I don't know if thats apply by input data directly in the WebDataRocks instance in the code, or only apply by loading local or external json or csv files. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the input data size limit for WebDataRocks applies to both inline data and loaded from external files. The data size should not exceed 1MB for both cases.